# API where i can get min and max price daily, going back months/years

Tags: historical-trade-data

I'm looking for an API service, where i can get historical data.
Something like: for each date:

- max price & time of day
- min price & time of day

Is there any service that provides this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but they are paid. Take a look at https://bitcoinaverage.com/ and https://coinmarketcap.com/ which are the big 2 services for this.